# gradle exclude run task for subproject

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have the following project-structure:

```
Root project 'rmi-tutorial'
+--- Project ':client'
+--- Project ':lib'
\--- Project ':server'
```

When I execute the run task of the root-project I will get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':lib:run'.
```

How can I exclude the :lib subproject from being run? I don't want to exclude the subproject completly and I also don't want to exclude it manually via command line parameters. When I execute the "build" task of the root-project it should build lib. When i execute "run" of the root-project it should run only the sub-projects "server" and "client".

Moreover server should be run before client. Any idea how to accomplish this without starting it manually in the correct order?

I know that I can do:

```
gradlew.bat build
gradlew.bat server:run
gradlew.bat client:run
```

but that is not what i want to do. I would prefer something like this:

```
gradlew.bat run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `run` task is created by the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/application_plugin.html), but the plugin is not designed for library projects. You could only apply the [Distribution Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) (`apply plugin: 'distribution'`) or the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html) (`apply plugin: 'java'`), which are both implicitly applied by the Application Plugin. This way, your `lib` subproject would not contain a `run` task and only the `run` tasks of the subprojects `client` and `server` would be executed.

Otherwise, if you really need the Application Plugin, you could exclude the `run` task via the [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) object in your `settings.gradle` file:

```
[...] // include subprojects

startParameter.excludedTaskNames << ':lib:run'
```

This task will be excluded from each build.

To manage the [order of tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks), you can use the methods `shouldRunAfter` and `mustRunAfter` (just like `dependsOn`):

```
tasks.getByPath(':client:run').mustRunAfter(tasks.getByPath(':server:run'))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea how I can `fork` the server process? Because now it hangs in the state `:server:run` because the java application will not fork.

Comment: If you have another problem, please ask another question.